# Rails Instance Variable Conflict between Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, mutex, puma

I have an array of prices: @price_queue.

It is persisted in PostgreSQL as **Prices.find(1).price_list** and is seeded.

When a transaction is initiated, the transaction takes the next price in @price_queue, and gets sent to a payment processor for the charge.

```
def create

  price_bucket = Prices.find(1)

  price_bucket.with_lock do                          
    @price_queue = price_bucket.price_list         
    @price = @price_queue.shift                    
    price_bucket.save                              
  end

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          :email        => params[:stripeEmail],
          :card         => params[:stripeToken],
      )
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :customer     => customer.id,
          :amount       => @price * 100,
      )

      if charge["paid"]
        Pusher['price_update'].trigger('live', {message: @price_queue[0]})
      end
```

If the transaction succeeds, it should get rid of the @price it holds.
If it fails, the price should be placed back into @price_queue.

```
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    @price_queue.unshift(@price)
    Pusher['price_update'].trigger('live', {message: @price_queue[0]})
    price_bucket.price_list = @price_queue
    price_bucket.save
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

I have found a major bug when testing, at milliseconds intervals, two failing transactions and then a passing one.

```
price_queue = [100, 101, 102, 103, ...]
```

User 1 gets 100 (confirmed on Stripe dashboard)

User 2 gets 101 (confirmed on Stripe dashboard)

User 3 gets 102 (confirmed on Stripe dashboard)

**Expected:**

Assuming no unshift has occurred yet

```
price_queue = [103, 104, ...]
```

User 1 fails, puts 100 back

```
price_queue = [100, 103, ...]
```

User 2 fails, puts 101 back

```
price_queue = [101, 100, 103, ...]
```

User 3 passes, 102 disappears

**What really happens:**

```
price_queue = [101, 102, 103, 104, ...]
```

As we can see, 100 is disappearing, although it should be back in the queue, 101 is back in the queue (most probably not by expected behaviour), and 102 is being put back in the queue, even though it shouldn't even traverse the rescue path.

I am using Puma on Heroku.

I have tried storing the price in **session[:price]**, **cookie[:price]**, assigning it to a local variable **price**, to no avail.

I've been reading around and figured this could be a scope problem cause by a multithreaded environment, where @price is leaking to other controller actions and being reassigned or mutated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (also feel free to critic my code)

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer right now but your rescue clause can overwrite changes to prices made by other instances

Comment: @FrederickCheung Please elaborate when you got time

Comment: I've deleted my answer since clearly the stripe dashboard shows the 100, 101, 102 values were sent.  On the dashboard, the first two failed and the third was successful?

Comment: Yes, exactly @SteveTurczyn

Comment: I wonder if this is something with how arrays are implemented in PostgreSQL? because we're assuming the array in `@price_queue` and in `price_bucket.price_list` are the same object which may no longer be true outside the `with_lock` block. In which case the model isn't being updated in the rescue block. What if you did `price_bucket.price_list = @price_queue` immediately before the `price_bucket.save` in the `rescue` block?

Comment: Even if that didn't fix it, it would be better-documented code.  Looking at the rescue block there's no intuitive way of knowing that `@price_queue` is the same object as one of the model's attributes you're saving.

Comment: Just tried it with a Fail Fail Pass (in order). Before transaction `@price_queue = [100, 101, 102, 103, ... ]`.  On the Stripe dashboard, 100 failed, 101 failed, 102 passed. After transaction: `@price_queue = [ 103, 104, 105, ... ]`.

Comment: It appears the unshifts are not taking place

Comment: Maybe the second price_bucket.save is falling? If you change it to price_bucket.save! (With exclamation point) does it raise an exception?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, it turns out the `price_queue` needed to be reloaded from the database, because other users would have had updated it.

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense. Much clearer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with instance variables leaking or anything like that - just some classic  race conditions going on here. Two possible timelines:

- request 1 fetches prices from the database (the array is [100,101,102])
- request 2 fetches prices from the database (the array is [100,101,102] -  a separate copy)
- request 1 locks prices, removes a price and saves
- request 2 locks prices, removes a price and saves

The important thing here is that request 2 is using an old copy of prices that doesn't include the changes made by request 1: Both of the instances will shift the same value off the array (the requests could be the different threads on the same puma worker, different workers or even different dynos - doesn't matter)

Another failure scenario would be

- request 1 fetches prices, removes a price and saves. The array in the database is [101,102,103,...], the in memory array is [101,102,103, ...]
- request 2 fetches prices, removes a price and saves. The array in the database is [102,103,...]
- request 2's stripe transaction succeeds
- request 1's stripe transaction fails, so it puts 100 back onto the array and saves. Because you haven't reloaded from the database this overwrites the changes from request 2.

To fix this properly I'd split out the logic for acquiring and replacing a price into their own methods - something like

```
class Prices < ActiveRecord::Base

  def with_locked_row(id)
    transaction do
      row = lock.find(id)
      result = yield row
      row.save #on older versions of active record you need to tell rails about in place changes
      result
    end

  def self.get_price(id)
    with_locked_row(id) {|row| row.pricelist.shift}
  end

  def self.restore_price(id, value)
    with_locked_row(id) {|row| row.pricelist.unshift(value}
  end
end
```

You'd then do

```
  Prices.get_price(1) # get a price
  Prices.restore_price(1, some_value) #put a price back if the charging failed
```

The key differences between this and your original code are that:

- I acquire a locked row and update it, rather than acquiring a row and then locking it. This eliminates the window in the first scenario I outlined
- I don't keep using the same active record object after I've released the lock - as soon as the lock has been released someone else might be changing it behind your back.

You could also do this via optimistic locking (i.e without explicit locks). The only thing that would change code-wise would be

```
    def with_locked_row(id)
      begin
        row = lock.find(id)
        result = yield row
        row.save #on older versions of active record you need to tell rails about in place changes
        result
      rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
        retry
      end
    end
```

You would need to add a non null integer column with default value 0 called `lock_version` for this to work.

Which performs better depends on how much concurrency you experience, what other accesses there are to this table and so on. Personally I would default to optimistic locking unless I had a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: The first scenario hasn't happened yet in over 1000 tests. I am using pessimistic locking. As I mentioned, failed or succeeded, no two payment transactions are ever the same, so the `shift`, and the Stripe charge are behaving properly. The problems arise when comes the time to place a failed transaction's price back into the array. @FrederickCheung

Comment: Nonetheless I will give this a shot shortly and return with news

Comment: @shiva  I explained, when you put the failed transaction back you run the risk of overwriting what other transactions have done

Comment: Indeed, the problem was that the queue wasn't being reloaded before unshifting. I implemented it with a lock as suggested. Thank you for your help @FrederickCheung